# Perform several mathematic operations

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

## The task:

You have to input 2 numbers and output the results of several operations done with them.

## Details:

Input 2 floating point numbers, x != 0 and y != 0 via stdin, command line or function arguments.
Output x+y,
       x*y,
       x^y (pow(x,y), not x XOR y),
       x-y,
       y-x,
       x/y and
       y/x on STDOUT separated by newlines, commas or spaces.

For languages which doesn't support floats, you may use an external library, implement them yourself or you can not participate :(
Standard loopholes apply, the shortest code in bytes wins. Good luck!

Comment: You want us to print the results of each?

Comment: @jacksonecac Yes.

Comment: What is unclear about this, please?

Comment: And if it's still unclear, how could I do it better?

Comment: Please specify *what* operations these are. Is `x^y` XOR or exponentiation?

Comment: Uh, if that's the problem... Fixed in 1 min.

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev: No, the linked challenge is about one integer changed with commands, and this is about two floats which are involved in several calculations. Still thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @MegaMan You have to realize, that's the same in many languages. So this is still a duplicate.

Comment: @mbomb007 It's still a difference. In the linked question you have to enter the commands, which isn't the case here. I can understand you, but this is not the same.

Comment: @MegaMan If parsing is the only difference, it's too similar.

Comment: @mbomb007 well, on the accumulator you can only add 1, substract 1, multiply by 2 and divide by 2. I think that's a big difference...

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 15 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Takes x as left argument and y as right argument.

```apl
+,×,*,-,-⍨,÷,÷⍨
```

Simply a long train of forks (3-trains):

`+,` the sum, followed by

`×,` the product, followed by

`*,` the exponentiation, followed by

`-,` the difference, followed by

`-⍨,` the swapped difference, followed by

`÷,` the ratio, followed by

`÷⍨` the swapped ratio

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%D7%2C*%2C-%2C%F7%2C%F7%u2368%20%u22C4%202%20f%204&run)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```
x#y=mapM print[x+y,x*y,x**y,x-y,y-x,x/y,y/x]
```

Example: `4 # 5` prints

```
9.0
20.0
1024.0
-1.0
1.0
0.8
1.25
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 40 bytes

```
->x,y{puts x+y,x*y,x**y,x-y,y-x,x/y,y/x}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 68 bytes

```
(x:Float,y:Float)=>Seq(x+y,x*y,math.pow(x,y),x-y,x/y,y/x)map println
```

Pretty striaghtforward.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 36 bytes

```
{a,b->print([a+b,a-b,a/b,a*b,a**b])}
```

Output:

```
({a,b->print([a+b,a-b,a/b,a*b,a**b])})(5.034,2.0568)
```

Results in:

```
[7.0908, 2.9772, 2.4474912485, 10.3539312, 27.777623862468822]
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 15 bytes

Equivalent to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97589/43319).

Takes x as left argument and y as right argument.

```
+,*,^,-,-~,%,%~
```

Simply a long train of forks (3-trains):

`+,` the sum, followed by

`*,` the product, followed by

`^,` the exponentiation, followed by

`-,` the difference, followed by

`-~,` the swapped difference, followed by

`%,` the ratio, followed by

`%~` the swapped ratio

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 66 bytes

```
param($x,$y)$x+$y;$x*$y;[math]::Pow($x,$y);$x-$y;$y-$x;$x/$y;$y/$x
```

Very boring, does exactly what it says on the tin. Each statement (separated by `;`) is evaluated and left on the pipeline. At program completion, everything left on the pipeline is implicitly printed via `Write-Output`.

Long because PowerShell uses `$` to delineate variables, and it also doesn't have a `^` or `**` or equivalent operator, so we need a .NET call.

Note that the `Write-Output` will *display* as integer values, even if the input is floats. Running a `.GetType()` will show the output to be `System.Double` however.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\perform-several-mathematic-operations.ps1 5.0 6.0
11
30
15625
-1
1
0.833333333333333
1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 106 bytes

```
void r(float x,float y){System.Console.WriteLine($"{x+y} {x*y} {Math.Pow(x,y)} {x-y} {y-x} {x/y} {y/x}");}
```